# solving the equation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

let there be a function $ f(x)= \ln x-kx^2, k>0$ determine for whihc values of $ k$ ,the equation $f(x)=0.5$ has a single solution; attemp to solve:

$$0.5 = \ln x-kx^2$$
$$kx^2 +0.5 = \ln x $$

also in point of intersection dervatives are equal hence wiil also get :$$2kx = 1/x$$

solving the system of $$kx^2 +0.5 = \ln x $$ $$2kx = 1/x$$ will yield $x=e , k=1/(2e^2)$. Said $k$ is what we were looking for....

Is this solution a satisfactory one?

Comment: Seems ok to me.  I was a little uncomfortable about the intersection/tangency thing, but drawing a picture makes it pretty clear I suppose.

Comment: it is not correct universly but in this particular case, it does...

Comment: although if $k$ were for instance such that there would be two solutions, how would I be able to tell the diffrence?

Comment: Draw a picture of $ln x$ and $kx^2$.  You can see that in the event of a single intersection they share a tangent at that point.  In the event of two intersections their slopes are different.  If one wanted to turn this into a general rule I suspect it would involve two functions of differing concavity agreeing at a point, but I'm just giving my first impression.

Comment: Actually now that I am looking at it, what I suggested is not enough for a general fact.

Answer (score 2):

The two functions $kx^2+.5$ and $\ln(x)$ are increasing for $x>0, k>0$. The first is concave up and the second is concave down. So if their graphs  intersect once they will intersect again. Thus the only way for there to be one solution is if the graphs are tangent (double solution) at the point of intersection. Then you can solve the derivative problem and get the solutions as you have shown.

Comment: I understand...so what do you make of my suggested solution then?

Comment: @Bak1139 It is important to mention concavity

Comment: I added a drawing of the two graphs